# Error While creating Android App

Tags: java, android, classcastexception

```
private class WeatherTask extends AsyncTask<String , Void, Weather>{
    @Override
    protected Weather doInBackground(String... params) {
        String data=((new WeatherHttpClient()).getWeatherData(params[0]));

        weather = JSONWeatherParser.getWeather(data);

        Log.v("Data:",weather.currentCondition.getDescreption());
        return weather;
    }
```

I am new to android development can somebody help me how to solve this exception error occurred during running the app

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
Process: com.example.elangocandy.weatherapp, PID: 2764
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.android.okhttp.internal.huc
```

Comment: Cross check your response with the model class

Comment: Where are you initializing the weather object? That might be the problem

Answer (score 0):

`Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.android.okhttp.internal.huc`

ClassCastException is thrown when you are trying to cast an object in to a type that is not actually in.  I think the `WeatherHttpClient` is a class written by you. So if you are doing a class casting inside this class you should do a `instance of` check before the casting.

I can provide more details if you can post the  body of the `WeatherHttpClient` class.

Are you using volley library to do the network call?

Comment: I have posted the body of WeatherHttpClient

Comment: Apparently `WeatherHttpClient` class is OK. I cannot give further comments as your problem is not very clear. It may be a problem of the `JSONWeatherParser` class or in the weather object. What you have to do is debug the app and find the line of the error. Or of you are not familiar with debugging keep only the `String data=((new WeatherHttpClient()).getWeatherData(params[0]));` line and remove all other lines from the `doInBackground` method and check. Continue this by adding other lines one by one.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class WeatherHttpClient {
public String getWeatherData(String place){
    HttpsURLConnection connection=null;
    InputStream inputStream=null;

    try {
        connection = (HttpsURLConnection)(new URL(Utils.BASE_URL + place)).openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.connect();

        //Read the Response
        StringBuffer stringBuffer=new StringBuffer();
        inputStream=connection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String line=null;

        while ((line=bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
            stringBuffer.append(line + "\r\n");
        }
        inputStream.close();
        connection.disconnect();

         return stringBuffer.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
      return null;
}
```

}